# Did i solved the equation correctly?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, roots

while I was solving linear equations for my math high school classes I found an interesting problem to solve.

Here is the equation

$a^2x+4=a\cdot(x+4)\\
a^2x+4 =ax+4a\\
a^2x-ax=4a-4\\a\cdot(a-1)\cdot x=4\cdot(a-1)$

CASE 1:
Now we can see that we can divide by $a-1$ and then by $a$ to solve for $x$ and we can see that $a\ne0 \text{ and }\\a-1\ne0, a\ne1$

$x=\frac{4\cdot(a-1)}{a\cdot(a-1)}=\frac{4}{a}$

CASE 2: $a=0$

$0\cdot(0-1)\cdot x=4\cdot(0-1)\\0=-4$

We can see that for $a=0$ the equation has no solution in $\mathbb R$

CASE 3: $a=1$

$1\cdot(1-1)\cdot x = 4\cdot(1-1) \\ 0=0$

We can see that for $a=1$ the solution for the equation is every number in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Your work is correct. But an even easier way of finding the solution is factorising the equation so you have $(ax-4)(a-1)=0$. This can be easier than trying to do the case where a factor is $0$ and another case where the factor is nonzero.

Comment: Seems ok to me !

Comment: Your solution is correct but I found "Now we can see that we can divide by a−1 and then by a to solve for x and we can see that a≠0 and a−1≠0,a≠1" to be hard to read and rather backwards.  Being able to divide by a-1 doesn't imply or "make" a≠0 or a≠1.  It goes the other way: a≠1 and a≠0 implies we con divide by a-1.  Also as a is a given constant we can conclude it can not be 0 as that makes the system inconsistant.

Comment: it's probably not okay to talk about deleted answers but I want to point out that when you stated You can not divide be zero and so ax=0x = 4 you can not say x = 4/a = 4/0 it has no solutions you were correct and when the poster said 4/0 = infnty and has infinite solutions, that was wrong. I know subtlties can be difficult to a student and it's easy to think "Well, I have the general idea but I don't get these fine distinctions.".  I want you to know that is NOT the case here.  You *do* understand and were completely right.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I know that I'm not very good in writing text while doing math, can someone help me how to fix the text for this problem